# Select with ability to add new option item on mobile form

Tags: forms, mobile, input-fields

I'm not quite sure what kind of form field to use for a mobile app screen. It's for animals where "Breed" is selected from what's already available in the database AND I need to give the user the ability to add a new breed that isn't in the database yet.

I don't know what that field would be called and what could I use to make obvious to the user that they can add a new breed on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

A text field input with autocomplete is the easiest and fastest way for most mobile users to enter a word or phrase.

Since breed names is an existing list that's easy list to obtain, the app can easily autocomplete to all breed names whether the breed name has been "added" by a user.

The results is where users would be shown the next step or shown how to add a new breed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Breed" options are coming in the form of list.

Two possible solutions:

**Solution 1**

- When user navigates to Breed list page, show "Add Breed" button on the top/bottom depending on the OS.
- Wllow them to add a new breed and check if it is available on the list in parallel (auto suggestion)
- Walidate if the entered value is new or existing and prompt users about action
- Save the value

**Solution 2**

Add **"other"** category in "Breed " (dropdown or list view) at the end. Once user select **"other"** let them add a new breed through input box (go to step 2nd in first solution)

btw, it would make more sense if you present screens with questions.